# Using Keyup Event Globally

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dom-events

How would I go about using JavaScript on my web page page to call a function anytime there is a `keyup` event globally, so it isn't attached to textbox. I need it to work for every key on the keyboard. I am very new to JavaScript and having a lot of trouble interpreting the documentation

Comment: what have u tried?  http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please read the [faq]. Typically questions are accompanied by code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
$(document).keyup(function() {});
```

**Javascript**

```
document.onkeyup = function(event) {}
```